# collaborative on-prem mind mapping

Tags: collaboration, mind-mapping

I am searching for a true collaborative mind map solution like a collab. text editor but just for mind maps. Users should be able to work on the same mind map at the same time.

- mind map
- collaborative (simultaneous)
- no cloud
- (preferably open source)

Comment: There's a Mindmap app for Nextcloud. I've not tried it myself, but might that fit your needs? Completely self-hosted. But if you only need the Mindmap feature, that might be a bit much overhead.

Comment: Sadly [Mind Map](https://apps.nextcloud.com/apps/files_mindmap) does not support simultaneous editing.

Comment: Ah, sad indeed. Sorry, didn't know that. Wasn't there a second one? [Mindmaps](https://apps.nextcloud.com/apps/mindmaps)? Not tried either, just saying…

Comment: That one is not in the apps collection of the latest stable Nextcloud version and seems to be deprecated.